# Python on CentOS 5.x

Tags: python, centos5, mod-python

CentOS 5.x comes with python 2.4 preinstalled. I'd like to use a newer version, but I don't want to break anything.

How should I install a newer version without causing problems?

How can I force mod_python to use newer python, instead of 2.4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.6 is available via [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).  To enable EPEL for your box, just do a:

```
rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Then, to install Python 2.6:

```
yum install python26
```

there is also a mod_python from there too:

```
yum install python26-mod_python
```

To find additional packages: `yum search python26`

Comment: will it replace the system's version? I think this can break something.

Comment: No, it installs in parallel as `python26`.

Comment: python26-mod_python will automatically replace mod_python ?

Comment: By default, according to the [changelog](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/python26-mod_python.html), it sounds like it will only load if mod_python isn't already loaded.  More details can be found [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638362).  So it sounds like you will have to either remove the old mod_python (`yum remove mod_python`), or prevent it from loading (edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/python.conf`) to use python26-mod_python.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile python2.x with another user (i use py26 as username) by

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.7/Python-2.6.7.tgz
tar xzvf Python-2.6.7.tgz
cd Python-2.6.7
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python
make
make install
```

then add `$HOME/python/bin` to `$PATH`, so python2.6 only used by py26 user